# Sliding marker on link hover with jQuery

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery, html, css

The following code is for a vertical menu, where I needed a marker to slide down next to a link upon hovering over said link. Therefore I needed to change CSS properties of a HTML element (the top-margin in this case).

What I've done in jQuery is add a class ('.movedown1' or '.movedown2') to the marker div ('#slide') when the mouse hovers over one of the links ('#menulink2' or '#menulink3'), and remove the class when the mouse stops hovering over the link.

It works!...But is it a clean method to add/change CSS properties of a HTML element? Does it follow best practices for jQuery? I've only used jQuery a few times in the past so I'm not familiar with best practices.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/AlbertMcTorre/pen/PgjXBy)

HTML(Pug):

```
#slide

#menu
  a.menulink#menulink1(href="#")
    p RED
  a.menulink#menulink2(href="#")
    p BLUE
  a.menulink#menulink3(href="#")
    p GREEN
```

CSS (Sass)

```
a
  color: white
  text-decoration: none

#slide
  width: 10px
  height: 30px
  background-color: red
  position: absolute
  border-radius: 15px
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out


.movedown1
  margin-top: 40px
  background-color: blue !important

.movedown2
  margin-top: 80px
  background-color: green !important

#menu
  margin-left: 30px

.menulink
  height: 40px
  width: 70px
  display: block

.menulink p
  height: 30px
  width: 70px
  margin: 0px
  border-radius: 15px
  display: flex
  align-items: center
  justify-content: center

#menulink1 p
  background: red
#menulink2 p
  background: blue
#menulink3 p
  background: green
```

jQuery

```
$('#menulink2').hover(
  function(){
  $('#slide').addClass('movedown1');
  },
  function(){
  $('#slide').removeClass('movedown1')  

});

$('#menulink3').hover(
  function(){
  $('#slide').addClass('movedown2');
  },
  function(){
  $('#slide').removeClass('movedown2')  

});
```

Comment: Really clean code. great work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### JavaScript

This code violates the [***D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself* principle](https://deviq.com/don-t-repeat-yourself/) because there is some redundancy in the code to handle the hover events, but for a beginner it might be challenging to know how to abstract the common code.

One way to reduce the redundancy is to define a mapping of id values to classes to toggle. This can be done with a plain-old JavaScript [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), like below, or with a [Map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object.

```
const targetClassMapping = {
  'menulink2': 'movedown1',
  'menulink3': 'movedown2'
};
```

Then the code can utilize [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover2) on any element with the class name `menulink` with a single event handler that checks the `id` attribute (using the jQuery [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr) method) of the event target and if the `id` matches a key in that mapping it then calls [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass) on the slider element. Additionally, `$('slider')` can be stored in a variable and used when needed instead of querying the DOM each time.

```
const slide = $('#slide');
$('.menulink').hover(function(){
  const id = $(this).attr('id');
  if (id && id in targetClassMapping) {
    slide.toggleClass(targetClassMapping[id]);
  }
});
```

This could also be done without jQuery, though the code wouldn't be quite as succinct.

```
const slider = document.getElementById('slide');
const targetClassMapping = {
  'menulink2': 'movedown1',
  'menulink3': 'movedown2'
};
['mouseover', 'mouseout'].forEach(type => document.addEventListener(type, handleMouseEventOnMenuLink));
function handleMouseEventOnMenuLink(event) {
  if (event.target.parentNode) {
    const id = event.target.parentNode.id;
    if (id in targetClassMapping) {
      const method = event.type === 'mouseover' ? 'add' : 'remove';
      slider.classList[method](targetClassMapping[id]);
    }
  }
}
```

### CSS / SASS

I see a couple lines with `!important`.

> ```
> .movedown1
>   margin-top: 40px
>   background-color: blue !important
>
> .movedown2
>   margin-top: 80px
>   background-color: green !important
> ```

It is wise to not depend on `!important` if possible, [to avoid confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3427813/1575353). You can remove the `!important` from those background color styles if you make the selectors more specific than just `#slide` - e.g. `#slide.movedown1` and `#slide.movedown2`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by changing the location of your `#slide` element so that it is a sibling of `menulink`. I would also remove the paragraph tags as they are redundant and reduce the dependence on id tags. Rsather use classes.

Here is how I would implement it (though you could also use a flex layout)

```
#menu
  a.menulink(href="#") RED
  a.menulink(href="#") BLUE
  a.menulink(href="#") GREEN
  .slide
```

````
.slide
  width: 10px
  height: 30px
  background-color: red
  position: absolute
  top: 8px
  border-radius: 15px
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out

.menulink:hover:nth-child(2) ~ .slide
  margin-top: 40px
  background-color: blue

.menulink:hover:nth-child(3) ~ .slide
  margin-top: 80px
  background-color: green

#menu
  margin-left: 30px

.menulink
  display: block
  margin: 5px 16px
  width: 70px
  display: block
  height: 30px
  line-height: 30px
  border-radius: 15px
  color: white
  text-decoration: none
  text-align: center

.menulink:nth-child(1)
  background: red
.menulink:nth-child(2)
  background: blue
.menulink:nth-child(3)
  background: green
```
````